# Angular 6 - placeholder text not visible for select list of options

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I cannot see the select list placeholders in chrome browser version 71 on my windows 10 laptop.

Currently just see white blank instead of placeholder text.

**This is my form html:**

```
       <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
         <select formControlName="sector" class="col-12 field">
            <option [value]="null" disabled="true">Select Sector*</option>
            <option [value]="sector" *ngFor="let sector of jobOptions.sectors">{{ sector }}</option>
          </select>
      </form>
```

**This is my form:**

```
  public createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      sector: [ null, [ Validators.required ]]
    });
  }
```

**This is what I see:**

[image]

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knuhqv

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that might help you :-

app.component.html:-

```
<select>
          <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select 
          language</option>
          <option *ngFor="let option of field.options" [value]="option.name"> 
          {{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

app.component.css :-

```
select > .placeholder {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: but wont that hide the placeholder? I want to show it by default

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public createForm(): void {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    sector: [ null, Validators.required ]
  });
```

}

and in template:

```
 <select formControlName="sector" class="col-12 field">
        <option value="null" disabled selected hidden >Select Sector*</option>
        <option [value]="sector" *ngFor="let sector of jobOptions.sectors">{{ sector }}</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `required` did the trick.

```
<select formControlName="sector" class="col-12 field" required>
   <option value="null" disabled selected hidden>Select Sector*</option>
   <option [value]="sector" *ngFor="let sector of jobOptions.sectors">
      {{ sector }} 
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: The question is related to `How to show placeholder for select`